# Should org-meta-return leave cursor on new empty headline?

Tags: org-mode

I'm observing the follow behavior, and I wonder if my Emacs is mis-configured, or this is normal. The `|` is the cursor.

```
* Test
** apples
** |bananas
** pizza
```

With my cursor before the "b" in "bananas", as shown above, I hit `M-return` (`org-meta-return`), and it changes the buffer to this:

```
* Test
** apples
** 
** bananas|
** pizza
```

It's not big deal, but it annoys me. If the meaning of the command is "start a new headline, before this one", why is the cursor going to the wrong place? It should be on the empty line, ready to start the new headline.

Is it a bug? Can I configure it do what I want?

M-x version => GNU Emacs 29.2 (build 2, x86_64-w64-mingw32) of 2024-02-01

Comment: Can't reproduce it. Can you reproduce it with `emacs -Q`? If not, bisect your init file to find out what's causing it.

Comment: Yes, just reproduced it with `-Q`.

Comment: What is the Org mode version? Maybe it's a bug that's been fixed.

Comment: org-version = 9.6.15

Comment: Turns out I was wrong. I *can* reproduce it with `emacs -Q` even on latest. Something in *my* configuration changes things but I have not figured out what yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following setting to your init file:

```el
(setq org-M-RET-may-split-line nil)
```

or customize the variable.

The doc string of the variable (C-h v org-M-RET-may-split-line) says:

```
org-M-RET-may-split-line is a variable defined in ‘org.el’.

Its value is nil
Original value was ((default . t))

Non-nil means M-RET will split the line at the cursor position.
When nil, it will go to the end of the line before making a
new line.
You may also set this option in a different way for different
contexts.  Valid contexts are:

headline  when creating a new headline
item      when creating a new item
table     in a table field
default   the value to be used for all contexts not explicitly
          customized
```

You might want to experiment with customizing the variable differently for different contexts, but I customized it to `nil` long ago and completely forgot about it: that has worked fine for me.

I don't really understand why the default behavior is as it is, but I haven't gone back through the ORG-NEWS file and/or any code changes affecting it. It may just be that the devs did not want to change a long-standing default behavior, however undesirable some people might find it.

EDIT: In response to the comment, I tried it (with both latest - "Org mode version 9.7-pre (release_9.6.19-1215-g67d937" to be exact - and also with 9.6.15) with `emacs -Q -l /path/to/minimal.el /path/to/test/file.org`. The `minimal.el` file just sets up `load-path` to get Org from my git repo and sets the above option. Starting with the following file:

```
* Test
** apples
** bananas
** pizza
```

and the cursor on the `b` of `bananas`, then `M-RET` produces this:

```
* Test
** apples
** bananas
** |
** pizza
```

with the cursor where indicated by `|`

Starting with the original file and with the cursor on the first asterisk on the same line, then `M-RET` produces this:

```
* Test
** apples
** |
** bananas
** pizza
```

Comment: That's an improvement, but it removes the feature they describe in the info doc (2.4 Structure Editing) - where if you are the beginning the line, it should open the new item *before* this one. Upvoting because this is helpful. I will ask the org list about it.

Comment: That works for me (with `emacs -Q -l minimal.el` where the minimal.el file does nothing more than set the option above). It works for both 9.6.15 and latest. I assume that by "the beginning of the line" is meant "before all the asterisks" i.e. column 0.

Comment: Yes, that's part of where I got confused - before the content vs before the stars as well.

Comment: Check the `org-special-ctrl-a/e` setting. Default is `nil` but I set it to `t` which I find helpful to navigate through parts of a headline.